# how to integrate a web forms page in an aspx mvc page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to display the contents of an aspx web forms page inside an aspx mvc partial view.
 Both these pages are in different projects.
 I have tried including the web forms page inside the web mvc project , but it doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating web forms with MVC is entirely possible. See this blog post by [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx) for that.

and hers is some stack overflow previous  discussion links :

[Is it possible to share a masterpage between MVC and webforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841418/is-it-possible-to-share-a-masterpage-between-mvc-and-webforms)

[Launch an ASP MVC project from a normal .aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404745/launch-an-asp-mvc-project-from-a-normal-aspx-page)

[How to open MVC 4 view page from webform.aspx page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234423/how-to-open-mvc-4-view-page-from-webform-aspx-page)

```
Must think this : asp.net webfornm having asp.net controls , but MVC razor  view engine 
having html (cshtml) controls .
```

Refer this : [Custom controls with ASP.NET MVC Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582866/custom-controls-with-asp-net-mvc-razor)

and More Stack overflow answers was here : [Search of SO](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how%20to%20integrate%20a%20web%20forms%20page%20in%20an%20aspx%20mvc%20page?&oq=how%20to%20integrate%20a%20web%20forms%20page%20in%20an%20aspx%20mvc%20page?&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&ie=UTF-8#q=asp%20net%20controls%20razor%20stackoverflow)